# Does iOS6 fix the iOS5 bug: ALAssetsLibrary doesn't send ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

Has there been any progress on the iOS5 bug: http://www.openradar.me/10484334?

Recap: an app that makes use of the ALAsset framework will NOT respond to changes to the asset library when those changes occur via the camera (or similar asset dependent app).

So, background your app, foreground camera app, snap photo, background camera app, foreground your app. You will not see the changes in your photo thumbnail tableView.

Alternatively if someone can point me to example code that correctly implements the workaround mentioned in the radar bug I would be most appreciative. I have put the app I was building on hold as I could not get previous suggested fixes to work.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not fixed on my device. I have tried all sorts of things, such as deleting an album, adding a photo, etc., and I *never* get the ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification.

Comment: Yah. Extremely frustration. I can't imagine what people building photo manipulation apps are doing to get around this fundamental bug. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is fixed,but there is a another bug:

when you delete photos in photo album, the interface will be holded.